# Custom meta box data not saving after wrapping in class

Tags: custom-post-types

I followed this tutorial and got everything to display and save properly, however I wanted to create a new class for this to clean up the code. Unfortunately after doing so the data no longer saves and I haven't been able to fix the issue.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields--wp-23259

The meta box fields are output from a switch statement based on the contents of the $custom_meta_fields array.

```
class VPC_Customization_Meta_Boxes {

protected $custom_meta_fields = array();

function __construct() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'create_fields_array') );
    add_action( 'load-post.php', array( $this,'setup_boxes') );
    add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $this, 'setup_boxes') );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_scripts') ); 
    /* Create fields array on the 'add_meta_boxes' hook */

}

/* Meta box setup function. */
function setup_boxes() {

  /* Add meta boxes on the 'add_meta_boxes' hook. */
  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_boxes') );
  /* Save post meta on the 'save_post' hook. */
  add_action('save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta'));
}
```

...

```
// Save the Data
function save_meta($post_id) {

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['vpc_customization_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) 
        return;
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;
    // check permissions
    $post_type_slug = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post_type_slug );

    if( $post_type_slug === $_POST['post_type'] ){
        if( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) ) 
            return;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ($this->custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        $new = false;
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        if ( isset( $_POST[$field['id']] ) )
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ( isset( $new ) && $new != $old ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $new );
        } 
        elseif ( isset( $new ) && '' == $new && $old ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $old );
        }
    } // end foreach
}
```

One thing I'm not sure of is if I'm accessing $post and $post_ID properly from within in the class.

Full code: http://pastebin.com/rxnyeRar

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you need to add your save routine to a hook, which in this case would `save_post`.

```
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'create_fields_array') );
    add_action( 'load-post.php', array( $this,'setup_boxes') );
    add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $this, 'setup_boxes') );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_scripts') ); 

    //don't forget the save routine
    add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'save_meta') ); 

}
```

This is making the assumption that your `save_meta()` function is in the class and that your class is being properly instantiated.

Comment: Hi Helga!

Thanks for the quick response, I have the 'save_post' hook in the setup_boxes() function, my bad for not including that originally. If possible, would you be able to take a look at my pastebin?

Comment: I would remove the `setup_boxes` method completely and move both its functions into the contructor. See if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the data still isn't saving, but thank you.

Comment: Ok, but that helps us narrow down the source of the problem. I'm going to bed, but I am going to guess the problem is with your Nonce. What I sometimes do is replace all the `return` statements with `wp_die("this is the reason we failed here"` type messages that help you pinpoint *where* the save routine is failing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use wp_die, it turns out that within the `save_meta()` method I'm unable to access the `$custom_meta_fields` array. I haven't been able to figure out why yet.

Comment: The `add_meta_boxes` hook is probably not called before `save_post` is fired.